# How to restart Mozila Firefox browser from firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am creating a firefox extension. I have to restart firefox after certain condition from extension's js file.
So how can I restart firefox browser by extension javascript ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this code](https://github.com/erikvold/restartless-restart-ffext/blob/3d2b07b1aa7d10118dbb9165e6e96883b7160f32/src/bootstrap.js#L157-L173):

```
function restart() {
  let canceled = Cc["@mozilla.org/supports-PRBool;1"]
      .createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsPRBool);

  Services.obs.notifyObservers(canceled, "quit-application-requested", "restart");

  if (canceled.data) return false; // somebody canceled our quit request

  // disable fastload cache?
  if (getPref("disable_fastload")) Services.appinfo.invalidateCachesOnRestart();

  // restart
  Cc['@mozilla.org/toolkit/app-startup;1'].getService(Ci.nsIAppStartup)
      .quit(Ci.nsIAppStartup.eAttemptQuit | Ci.nsIAppStartup.eRestart);

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will invoke the already existing Mozilla restart command (which makes sure that all the appropriate cleanup is done).

This will work from a context where you have access to the browser window element (i.e. from a dialog window which you have opened (e.g. options dialog)):

```
window.opener.content.document.getElementById('cmd_restartApp').doCommand();
```